# How do I import an mdf database file into MySQL?

Tags: 12.10, mysql

I have an .mdf file(which is supposed to have database). I'm using Ubuntu 12.10 .

I want to import the database into `mysql.5.5.28-0ubuntu0.12.10.2` (Ubuntu) as this is version I'm using for mysql.

Answer (score 2):

You have some options:

1. You can use MSSQL Express and interface utility to make a raw sql dump of the database. As [this](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187510.aspx)
2. Use http://opendbcopy.sourceforge.net/

Answer (score 1):

mdf is a SQL Server database file. You can use http://opendbcopy.sourceforge.net/ to copy your database.

Comment: what drivers i need to import in lib???

Comment: com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc MIcrosoft SQL Server JDBC

Answer (score 1):

There is infact a process ready to go with MySQL Workbench.

Here is the documentation:

- http://www.mysql.com/products/workbench/migrate/
- http://dev.mysql.com/doc/workbench/en/wb-migration-database-mssql.html

I have used it before, and I intend to use it again a few times this year.